# Giving a variable a value from a text file

Tags: batch-file

Before you say it's already been asked, yes I know. I've been researching this for the past hour and still can't figure out why it isn't working. I've directly copied and pasted code from an answer to this exact same question as shown below:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
pause
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (file.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
    pause
)
set var

pause
```

Now, this works perfectly fine, IF the "file.txt" has no spaces. If, however, the file name DOES contain spaces, the whole thing is futile. I've put the name in quotation marks, but then all the program does is set var1 to = "file with spaces.txt" and nothing else. In fact, putting quotation marks in anywhere screws everything up, regardless of spaces. I'm sure it's a really simple answer, I just can't seem to find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with `useback` (you can also use `usebackq`) option which will allow you to point the file path with double quotes and spaces in it:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
pause
FOR /F "useback tokens=*" %%A IN ("file.txt") do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
    pause
)
set var

pause
```

As a matter of fact it is not well documented by M$ (for command help message excerpt):

> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]
>
> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]
>
> or, if usebackq option present:
>
> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('string') DO command [command-parameters]
>
> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]

Comment: Works!!! Thank you so much. I spent so long trying to find out why it wasn't working, but after a massive headache and an hour wasted I decided to ask here. Really appreciate it!